# Outlook signature remove to pre-populated email in HTML/PHP

Tags: php, html, email, outlook

I have problem with "Outlook Signature and Pre-Populated" email.

If using normal `mailto` working fine but pass value with `mailto` signature is removed. So what I do?

```html
<a href="mailto:blake@test.com.au?subject=Cool Cats acr - 2144&amp;body=Order: %0D%0A%0D%0A 200 x Printed stickers 65x30 (approx.) with matte laminate.
White background, logo, Ph, Web, &quot;Your next service is due......&quot;
half of the stickers to use0402 198 255, other half to use0426 969 769 %0D%0A%0D%0AComments: %0D%0A ">With Pre-Populated </a>

<br>
<br>
<br>

<a title="0402 198 255" id="demo-basic12224" href="mailto:blake@test.com.au">without Pre-Populated</a>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Where is the php part?

Comment: if any solution using PHP ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40379643/is-it-possible-to-preserve-signature-using-mailto.